# When transporting hot liquids, is it better to use one large flask, or two small flasks?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, thermal-conductivity

If I want to transport a litre of a hot liquid, what's the best option?

1. Use a single one litre flask
2. [ two 500 ml flasks. (Preferable due to the distribution of weight across two people).

Which option will keep the liquid warmer for longer (accounting for the fact that the liquid will be drunk at regular intervals)?

Assume that all flasks have the same levels of insulation.

Comment: convection, conduction, and radiation. which is dominant? 

are the flasks closed or open (convection)? if the flasks are in contact with a surface, how much is the area of contact in the two situations and what is the temperature difference between the liquid and the surface (conduction)? What is the difference in total surface area between the two situations, and are the flasks of different material in the two situations (radiation)?  tldr give more information or hire an engineer and make them worry about this for you

Answer (score 2):

Heat transfer to the environment is dependent on the surface area that the heat if flowing through.  For the flask that carries double the mass of another flask, the larger flask has 1.6 times the area, but carries twice the ability to transfer heat as the smaller flask.  This means that the rate of temperature drop will be smaller in the larger flask.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the liquid will be consumed at regular intervals complicates the matter. Other practical issues might also be important.

If the liquid is consumed at one time, then it is clearly best to have it in one large flask, assuming that the ratio of surface area to volume is smaller - which it will be if the containers have the same shape. The rate of heat loss is proportional to the surface area, which is 26% bigger for the two smaller flasks compared with the one larger flask.

This difference could easily be outweighed by other considerations, such as being able to spread the load between two or more people, the convenience of handling a smaller flask, avoiding sloshing of contents, and saving heat by opening each flask fewer times.

If the liquid is consumed at intervals, the flask loses heat each time it is opened - much more quickly than while closed. If a flask is opened several times, it will cool down much quicker. Using several smaller flasks which are opened only once, although the 1st drink will be cooler than with one large flask, subsequent drinks are likely to be warmer.